# Why does this code to validate passwords always reject the input?

Tags: c, character-arrays

I tried to write a program that reads a password and accepts it only if it contains a dollar sign, an upper-case letter, and a digit. Here's the code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <ctype.h>

int main()
{
    int i=0;
    char chr;
    int dollar,upperC,number=0;
    char password[100];

    printf("enter the password\n\n");
    scanf("%s",password);

    for( i=0;i<=99;i++){
        chr=password;

        if(chr=='$'){
            dollar=1;
        }
        if(isdigit(chr)){
            number=1;
        }
        if(isalpha(chr)){
            if(isupper(chr)){
                upperC=1;
            }
        }
        if(dollar==1&&number==1&&upperC==1){
            printf("your password has accepted");
        }else{
            printf("your password has not accepted");
        }
        return 0;
    }
}
```

However, the program seems to reject all passwords, even ones where the conditions are fulfilled. Can someone help me see why this is?

Comment: First of all, using `%s` is just as bad as `gets`. You should not allow buffer overruns. Assigning the array to `chr` is nonsensical. When calling `isalpha` and related functions, you *must* ensure the characters you pass in are in the range of `unsigned char`. You do not do this.

Comment: Did you step through with a debugger?  That would almost instantly reveal the bug that I see.

Comment: @chris: Worse, `isalpha` and frinds are only valid for 0-128.  MSVC asserts when given a larger value.

Comment: @MooingDuck, WTH? I agree passing in others really has no meaning (apart from EOF), but wow.

Comment: and `i<=99` --> `password[i]`

Comment: @Deepanshu Bedi I reformatted the code that you posted so that it's properly indented. I'm not sure if the indentation issue was a copy/paste problem or whether your code is actually unindented. If you aren't properly indenting your code as you write it, I'd strongly encourage you to do so - the main issue (the `if` inside the `for`) is a lot easier to spot with proper indentation.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are several issues in this program; here are a few. As a note, most of these would probably be caught by a C compiler with the warning level cranked all the way up to maximum, so I recommend turning on warnings and making sure your programs compile cleanly before running them. With that said, here are some specific errors in the program:

When you write

```
int dollar,upperC,number=0;
```

C interprets this as equivalent to

```
int dollar;
int upperC;
int number = 0;
```

As you can see, `dollar` and `upperC` are uninitialized, so their values are undefined (but typically not zero). Try changing your code to set these to zero by writing

```
int dollar = 0, upperC = 0, number = 0;
```

Or, even better, include `<stdbool.h>` and write

```
bool dollar = false, upperC = false, number = false;
```

Additionally, note that your `if`/`else` test for the password is inside the `for` loop, meaning that you will test whether all character types are present without looking at all the possible characters in the input. To fix this, move your `if`/`else` outside of the loop.

This line is also incorrect:

```
chr=password;
```

This will not set `chr` to the next character of `password`. I think you meant

```
chr = password[i];
```

Finally, make sure that you don't loop up to index 99, inclusive. That might read past the end of the string. Instead, loop only up to the number of logical characters inside the string.

Hope this helps!

Comment: I missed that bug.  I saw a different one.  `chr=password;`

Answer (score 0):

Well I think you have a issue with your logic

```
if(dollar==1&&number==1&&upperC==1)
```

is incorrect because it is inside the forloop
you are evaluating the char and seeing if it is all (dollar, number, and upperC)

Also I think you are trying to evaulate each char so you need

```
chr = password[i];
```

Comment: That's technically correct, but not actually indicative of the root problem. The issue is not so much that it's testing one character to see if it's everything and more that this check should be after the loop, not inside.